# Is it possible to make this java code far more efficient?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

The code below is taking 27 seconds to load 51 images each image is about 22 KB (timed between the starting and ending alerts I inserted). Is it possible to make it a lot more efficient (I would like to get it to under 3 seconds)?

At first I thought it was the database so I put the alerts in to make sure and found it was this code.

Regards,

Glyn

```
public void renderYMAwardsTable(List<YouthMemberAwards> ymAwardsList) {
    if (!ymAwardsList.isEmpty()) {

        flexTableLink.clear();
        int linkRow = 0;
        int linkCol = 0;
        flexTableLeadership.clear();
        int leadershipRow = 0;
        int leadershipCol = 0;
        flexTableBoomerang.clear();
        int boomerangRow = 0;
        int boomerangCol = 0;
        flexTableAchievement.clear();
        int achievementRow = 0;
        int achievementCol = 0;
        flexTableSpecialInterest.clear();
        int specialInterestRow = 0;
        int specialInterestCol = 0;
        totalAwards = 0;


        Window.alert("Start populating page.");
        for (final YouthMemberAwards ymAwards : ymAwardsList) {
            // Display awards and, if applicable, date awarded

            if (((ymAwards.getCaAwardedDate() != null)
                    || (ymAwards.getAwArchivedDate() == null)
                    || (ymAwards.getCaAwardStarted().equals("Y"))
                    ) && (ymAwards.getAwStartedDate().before(ymEndDate))) {

                //Display each award in the correct area with:
                //  the date awarded, if applicable, and
                //  the date box shaded if the award has been started but not awarded

                String imageDataString = ymAwards.getAwAwardPicture();
                Image image = new Image(imageDataString);
                image.setWidth("75px");
                image.setHeight("75px");
                image.setStyleName("gwt-Selectable");

                final DateBox awardedDate = new DateBox();
                awardedDate.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")));
                awardedDate.setValue(ymAwards.getCaAwardedDate());
                awardedDate.setWidth("75px");
                awardedDate.setFireNullValues(true);                    
                //Check if the Youth Member has started the Award,
                //if they have then colour the date box Green.
                if (ymAwards.getCaAwardStarted()!= null){
                    if ((ymAwards.getCaAwardedDate() == null)
                            && (ymAwards.getCaAwardStarted().equals("Y"))){
                        awardedDate.setStyleName("gwt-Green-Background");
                    }else{
                        awardedDate.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
                    }
                }else{
                    awardedDate.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
                }

                //Tally the number of Awards the Youth Member has been awarded.
                if (ymAwards.getCaAwardedDate() != null){
                    totalAwards = totalAwards + 1;
                }

                //Display each Award in the appropriate category.
                if (ymAwards.getAwAwardType().equals("Link")){

                    flexTableLink.setWidget(linkRow, linkCol, image);
                    flexTableLink.setWidget(linkRow + 1, linkCol, awardedDate);
                    if (linkCol < 10){
                        linkCol = linkCol + 1;
                    }else{
                        linkCol = 0;
                        linkRow = linkRow + 2;
                    }

                }else{
                    if (ymAwards.getAwAwardType().equals("Leadership")){

                        flexTableLeadership.setWidget(leadershipRow, leadershipCol, image);
                        flexTableLeadership.setWidget(leadershipRow + 1, leadershipCol, awardedDate);
                        if (leadershipCol < 10){
                            leadershipCol = leadershipCol + 1;
                        }else{
                            leadershipCol = 0;
                            leadershipRow = leadershipRow + 2;
                        }

                    }else{
                        if (ymAwards.getAwAwardType().equals("Boomerang")){

                            flexTableBoomerang.setWidget(boomerangRow, boomerangCol, image);
                            flexTableBoomerang.setWidget(boomerangRow + 1, boomerangCol, awardedDate);
                            if (boomerangCol < 10){
                                boomerangCol = boomerangCol + 1;
                            }else{
                                boomerangCol = 0;
                                boomerangRow = boomerangRow + 2;
                            }

                        }else{
                            if (ymAwards.getAwAwardType().equals("Achievement")){

                                flexTableAchievement.setWidget(achievementRow, achievementCol, image);
                                flexTableAchievement.setWidget(achievementRow + 1, achievementCol, awardedDate);
                                if (achievementCol < 10){
                                    achievementCol = achievementCol + 1;
                                }else{
                                    achievementCol = 0;
                                    achievementRow = achievementRow + 2;
                                }

                            }else{
                                if (ymAwards.getAwAwardType().equals("Special Interest")){

                                    flexTableSpecialInterest.setWidget(specialInterestRow, specialInterestCol, image);
                                    flexTableSpecialInterest.setWidget(specialInterestRow + 1, specialInterestCol, awardedDate);
                                    if (specialInterestCol < 10){
                                        specialInterestCol = specialInterestCol + 1;
                                    }else{
                                        specialInterestCol = 0;
                                        specialInterestRow = specialInterestRow + 2;
                                    }

                                }else{
                                    //If not found then default to Special Interest.

                                    flexTableSpecialInterest.setWidget(specialInterestRow, specialInterestCol, image);
                                    flexTableSpecialInterest.setWidget(specialInterestRow + 1, specialInterestCol, awardedDate);
                                    if (specialInterestCol < 10){
                                        specialInterestCol = specialInterestCol + 1;
                                    }else{
                                        specialInterestCol = 0;
                                        specialInterestRow = specialInterestRow + 2;
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Add a click handler to the image
                image.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
                        //Store the data from this view for use in subsequent Views (ScoutAwardView).
                        AsyncCallback<ViewData> callback = new ViewDataStoreHandler<ViewData>();
                        rpc.setViewData(accountId, accountLevel, youthMemberID, ymAwards.getAwId(), "0", callback);

                        //If the Award has sub groups then display the Groups and allow one the 
                        //be selected to display the details. Otherwise, display the details.
                        if (ymAwards.getAwGrouped().equals("Y")) {
                            //Go to the AwardGroupView
                            navHandler2.go("AwardGroup");
                        }else{
                            //Go to the ScoutAwardView
                            navHandler2.go("ScoutAward");
                        }

                    }
                });

                //Add change handler for the awarded date.
                //Only a Leader or Administrator can update the date
                if (accountLevel.equals("Leader") || accountLevel.equals("Administrator")) {
                    awardedDate.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<java.util.Date>() {
                        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<java.util.Date> event) {
                            //Check for a null date and handle it for dateBoxArchived and dateBoxPackOut
                            java.sql.Date sqlDateAwarded = awardedDate.getValue() == null ? null : new java.sql.Date(awardedDate.getValue().getTime());
                            AsyncCallback<Void> callback = new YMAwardedDateHandler<Void>();
                            rpc.updateYMAwarded(youthMemberID, ymAwards.getAwId(), sqlDateAwarded, callback);

                            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                            AdjustAwardStock adjustAwardStock = new AdjustAwardStock(sqlDateAwarded, ymAwards.getAwId());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Window.alert("Finish populating page.");
    //Hide "Loading please wait" popup. 
    popup.hide();

    //Display the number of Awards earned.
    String totalAwardsString = Integer.toString(totalAwards);
    textBoxTotalAwards.setText(totalAwardsString);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling? If the code is I/O bound then there might not be a whole lot you can do.

Comment: Also, might want to look into the [`switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement

Comment: Instead of a long chain of if else statements, consider using switches. Efficiency and readability go hand in hand. Might be a good idea to incorporate some of the repetitive code for setting the rows and columns into a single method.

Comment: @user3580294: Don't give up so easily. Even I/O bound problems may be solved or at least alleviated. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Good points. I hadn't considered those...

Answer (score 6):

First of all, an image with 75x75 pixels size should not be 22kB. Even a PNG-24 image of this size is about 3kB, let alone GIF. Store your images in the correct sizes and the appropriate file format (use PNG or GIF). For 51 images that means a difference between 1MB and 150kB. This is the first big improvement.

Second, if you use a limited number of images, combine them into a single sprite. This will reduce the number of round-trip server calls from 51 (in your example) to 1. That's another huge improvement.

You don't need to make this sprite manually (unless you want to). You can use GWT's [ImageResource ClientBundle](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#ImageResource). Note that this sprite can be cached, so a browser won't need to load it every time a user visits this page.

The other suggestions (like using switch statements) are good for code readability and maintenance, but they won't give you a significant performance boost because your Java code is compiled into JavaScript, and the compiler is pretty smart.

Comment: And as a general rule, observe invariants, like the result of `new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")`.  It will be the same in every iteration of the loop, so try and only do the work once.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will change from jpeg to GIF and look into "sprite" as I have no idea what this is. I will also move the formatting. I have another issue I have discovered during testing that needs to be fixed first and then I will get back to you with the results. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi nitind, As I am creating a new DateBox for each person I do not see how I can set the observe invariant only once. Don't I have to set the observe invariants for each instance of the DateBox I create? If this is not so can you please direct me to a sample. Regards, Glyn. @nitind

Comment: You can declare DefaultFormat format = new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")); only once before the loop or as a static class variable, and then use this "format" object everywhere.

Comment: Hi Andrei, I have reduced the size of the images to 75px and converted them to GIF giving a considerable size saving; as you stated. I have also implemented DefaultFormat. This has resulted in a time to display saving of approximately 1 second. Not what I was hoping for.

Comment: The number of images displayed can vary as I have provided the ability for people to add and archive images in the application. Is that what you mean by "a limited number of images"? If I can still use sprite then are you able to point me to a good example that allows for multiple images that are read in from a DB? Thank you very much for your help. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Sprites are used when images do not change. If users can upload images, you have to do two things: (1) store them in the right size and format (e.g. resize if necessary before storing them), and (2) use a good storage option, like Google Cloud Storage, instead of a database.

Comment: What is imageDataString?

Answer (score 0):

For combining the images and other JS files, you can always use gzip functionality supported by browser so that all the files can b zipped and send to the browser to unzip. It will lot of network time and transferred data size will b much reduced.

Comment: Hi Anant, as reducing the size of my images by around 80% has had negligible affect I do not thing that zipping them will have much more benefit. Do you agree? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: It's not about the size always. You do realize that you have 51 images and browser will send request to the server for each image and wait for it to load? Hitting server for each image from multiple location, I don't prefer good option.

Comment: Hi Anant,Thank you very much for your comment. The results of my greatly decreasing the size of the images and only getting a 1 second performance improvement bears up your comment. Do you have a possible solution to improve the performance please? Regards, Glyn.